# d3.js - move group element and keep link connection

Tags: d3.js

I would like use mouse to move below sequence diagram elements groups (rectangle and lifecycle line,text labels) together and keep the links line connected as well. Just like the behavior of simulations. but for my case, I don't think it's meaningful to use simulation!

I guess move the g element then all child elements will be moved but no idea how to move the links since it use absolute values!

```js
sequence_uml_webrtc()
function sequence_uml_webrtc() {
  var data = `
ClientA , Signal Server: Connect
ClientB , Signal Server: Connect
ClientA , ClientA: Create PeerConnection
ClientA, ClientA: AddStream
ClientA, ClientA: CreateOffer
ClientA, Signal Server: Send OfferSDP
Signal Server, ClientB: Relay OfferSDP
ClientB,ClientB: CreateAnswer
ClientB, Signal Server: Send AnswerSDP
Signal Server,ClientA: Relay AnswerSDP
ClientA,Stun Server: Ask IP address
Stun Server,ClientA: OnIceCandidate
ClientA,Signal Server: Send candidate
Signal Server,ClientB: Relay candidate
ClientB,ClientB: AddIceCandidate
ClientB,Stun Server: Ask IP address
Stun Server,ClientB: OnIceCandidate
ClientB,Signal Server:Send candidate
Signal Server,ClientA: Relay candidate
ClientA,ClientA: AddIceCandidate
ClientA,ClientB: P2P channel

`

  var root = []
  var lines = data.split('\n')
  for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
    var line = lines[i]
    if (line == '') continue
    line = line.split(/[,:]/)
    for (var j=0;j<line.length;j++) {
      line[j] = line[j].replace(/\s*$/,"");
      line[j] = line[j].replace(/^\s*/,'')
    }
    root.push({sender:line[0],receiver:line[1],message:line[2]})
  }

  draw_sequence_diagram(root)
  function draw_sequence_diagram(data) {

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width',500)
    .attr('height',1200)
    .style('border','1px solid red'),
        margin = { top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 80 },
        width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    var lcolor = '#A80036'
    add_defs_blur(svg)
    add_defs_arr(svg,lcolor)

    // Graph title
    g.append('text')
      .attr('x', (width / 2))             
      .attr('y', 0 - (margin.top / 3))
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')  
      .style('font-size', '16px') 
      .text('sequence diagram');
    // Function to convert a string into a time
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M');
    var formatTime = d3.timeFormat('%e %B %H:%M:%S');
    // Set data
    // data.forEach(function(d) {
    //   d._time = parseTime(d._time);
    // });

    var senders = uniq(data.map(function(d){ return d.sender; }));
    var receivers = uniq(data.map(function(d){ return d.receiver; }));
    var classes = uniq2(senders, receivers);
    var objs = []
    classes.forEach((d,i) => {
      objs.push({name:d})
    })

    var XPAD = 100;
    var YPAD = 30;
    var VERT_SPACE = parseInt(width/classes.length);
    var VERT_PAD = 20;

    var MESSAGE_SPACE = 25;
    svg.attr("height", (data.length+2)*MESSAGE_SPACE);

    var MESSAGE_LABEL_X_OFFSET = -40;
    var MESSAGE_LABEL_Y_OFFSET = 75;
    var MESSAGE_ARROW_Y_OFFSET = 80;    

    var CLASS_WIDTH = VERT_SPACE-10;
    var CLASS_LABEL_X_OFFSET = -30;
    var CLASS_LABEL_Y_OFFSET = 25;

    var g1 = svg.selectAll('class-rect')
    .data(objs).enter().append('g')
    .call(
      d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", dragStart)
      .on("drag", drag)
      .on("end", dragEnd)
    );

    // Draw class labels
    var texts = g1.append('text')
    .attr("class", "class-label")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
    .attr("dy", "16px")
    .each( (d,i,n) => {
      d.w = n[i].getComputedTextLength() + 10
      d.x = XPAD + i * VERT_SPACE
      d.y = YPAD
    })
    .attr('x',d => d.x)
    .attr('y',d => d.y)

    // Draw classes
    var boxh = 24
    var rects =  g1.append("rect").lower()
    //.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + YPAD + ")")
    .attr("class", "class-rect")
    .attr('x',d => d.x - d.w/2)
    .attr('y',d => d.y)
    .attr('width',d => d.w)
    .attr('height',boxh)
    .attr('fill','#FEFECE') 
    //.attr('filter','url(#blur)')
    .attr('rx',5.5)
    .attr('ry',5.5)
    .attr('stroke','#A80036')
    .attr('stroke-width',1)

    // Draw vertical lines
    var vertlines = g1.append("line")
    .attr('stroke',lcolor)
    .attr("x1", d => d.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.y + boxh)
    .attr("x2", d => d.x)
    .attr("y2", d => d.y + VERT_PAD + data.length * (MESSAGE_SPACE+5));  

    // Draw message arrows
    var drawpath = function(m,i) {
      var y = MESSAGE_ARROW_Y_OFFSET + (i) * MESSAGE_SPACE;
      var ax = XPAD + classes.indexOf(m.sender) * VERT_SPACE
      var ay = y
      var bx = XPAD + classes.indexOf(m.receiver) * VERT_SPACE
      var by = y
      var path = ['M',ax,ay,'L',bx,by]
      if (m.sender == m.receiver) {
        var dx = MESSAGE_SPACE/4
        ay -= dx
        by += dx
        //path = ['M',ax,ay-dx,'l',4*dx,0,0,2*dx,-4*dx,0] 
        path = ['M',ax,ay,
                'C',ax+4*dx,ay+dx/8,bx+4*dx,by-dx/8,bx,by] 
      }
      return path.join(' ')
    }
    var g2 = svg.selectAll('clz-path')
    .data(data).enter().append('g')

    g2.append("path")
      .attr('stroke',lcolor)
      .attr('fill','none')
      .attr('d',drawpath)
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
      .append("text")
      .text(function (d) { return d.sourcetype; });

    // Draw message labels
    g2.append("text")
      .each((d,i) => {
      var x = XPAD + MESSAGE_LABEL_X_OFFSET + (((classes.indexOf(d.receiver) - classes.indexOf(d.sender)) * VERT_SPACE) / 2) + (classes.indexOf(d.sender)  * VERT_SPACE);
      var y = MESSAGE_LABEL_Y_OFFSET + i * MESSAGE_SPACE;
      if (d.sender == d.receiver) {
        x += MESSAGE_SPACE*2.5
        y += MESSAGE_SPACE/4
      }
      d.x = x
      d.y = y
    })
      .attr('x', d => d.x)
      .attr('y', d => d.y)
      .attr("dx", "5px")
      .attr("dy", "-2px")
      .attr("text-anchor", "begin")
      .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr('font-size',12)
      .text(function (d) { return d.message; });

    function GetCurrentTranslation(element) {
      var BasePos = [0, 0];
      var components = d3.transform(element.attr("transform"));
      BasePos[0] = components.translate[0];
      BasePos[1] = components.translate[1];
      return BasePos;
    }


    // var line = svg.append("svg:line")
    //     .attr("x1", parseInt(circ1.attr("cx")) + bpos1[0])
    //     .attr("y1", parseInt(circ1.attr("cy")) + bpos1[1])
    //     .attr("x2", parseInt(circ2.attr("cx"))+ bpos2[0])
    //     .attr("y2", parseInt(circ2.attr("cy")) + bpos2[1])
    //     .attr("stroke", "black");


    function dragStart(event,d) {

      d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
    }

    function drag(event,d) {
      d.x = event.x
      d.y = event.y
      d3.select(this).select('rect')
        .attr("x", d.x - d.w/2)
        .attr("y", d.y);
      d3.select(this).select('text')
        .attr("x", d.x)
        .attr("y", d.y);
      d3.select(this).select('line')
        .attr("x1", d => d.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.y + boxh)
        .attr("x2", d => d.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.y + VERT_PAD + data.length * (MESSAGE_SPACE+5));  

    }

    function dragEnd(event,d) {
      d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
    }

  }

  function uniq(arr) {
    let seen = new Set();
    arr.filter(d => {
      return seen.has(d) ? false : seen.add(d);
    });
    return seen
  }

  function uniq2(set1,set2) {
    let seen = new Set()
    set1.forEach(d => {
      seen.has(d) ? false : seen.add(d)
    })
    set2.forEach(d => {
      seen.has(d) ? false : seen.add(d)
    })
    return Array.from(seen)  
  }

  function add_defs_arr(svg,lcolor) {
    var aw = 8
    var ah = 4
    // Arrow style
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["end"])      
      .enter().append("svg:marker")
      .attr("id", String)
      .attr("viewBox",[0,0,2*aw+2,2*ah+2])
      .attr("refX", aw+1)
      .attr("refY", ah/2+1)
      .attr("markerWidth", aw*2+2)
      .attr("markerHeight", ah*2+2)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", ['M',1+aw/5,1+ah/2,'L',1,1,1+aw,1+ah/2,1,1+ah,'z'].join(' '))
      .attr('stroke',lcolor)
  }
  function add_defs_blur(svg) {
    var filter = svg.append('defs')
    .append('filter')
    .attr('height','300%')
    .attr('width','300%')
    .attr('id','blur')
    .attr('x',-1)
    .attr('y',-1)

    filter.append('feGaussianBlur')
      .attr('result','blurOut')
      .attr('stdDeviation',2.0)

    filter.append('feColorMatrix')
      .attr('id','blurOut')
      .attr('result','blurOut2')
      .attr('type','matrix')
      .attr('values','0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0')

    filter.append('feOffset')
      .attr('dx',4.0)
      .attr('dy',4.0)
      .attr('in','blurOut2')
      .attr('result','blurOut3')

    filter.append('feBlend')
      .attr('in','SourceGraphic')
      .attr('in2','blurOut3')
      .attr('mode','normal')
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395115/d3-js-move-group-element-and-keep-link-connection

Comment: Yes, now it draggable but the link still not updated after drag. since the line not below to the same group, still not know how to update it.